# How to stop other audio elements from playing with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have multiple default HTML5 audio players on a single HTML page. I'm trying to make it so when you play one file and then play the other. The first file will pause.

I started and created a function as follows:

```
allAudioEls = $('audio');

    function pauseAllAudio() {
       allAudioEls.each(function() {
          var a = $(this).get(0);
          a.pause();
       });
    }
```

whats the next step?

Comment: Hello, try to using `$(this)[0].pause();` instead of `$(this).get(0);
a.pause();`

Comment: @Nicolai I have to call the function when the audio players play button and pause button is clicked. I dont know how to bind the play or pause event to call that function and play the individual audio.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312714/adding-event-listener-to-audio-html5-tag-in-javascript) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aarongloege/fzXsT/light/)

Comment: the first link will show you how to add listener to "play" event. So you can just instead of "foo" place you pauseAllAudio function

Comment: @Nicolai I'm at the point where if I press play everything pauses, and that individual audio wont play. I need to run the function that stops all audio then start playing the audio that the play button is clicked. This is my code:   allAudioEls = $('audio');

$('audio').bind('play', function(e) {
  allAudioEls.each(function() {
    var a = $(this).get(0);
    a.pause();

  });
});

Answer (score 4):

I Think this is the best Answer for you : **[Stop other Audio ...](https://codepen.io/st-skumar/pen/qBEPLwP)**

You need to add the following Script only with JQuery.

**JavaScript:**

```
$("audio").bind("play",function (){
  $("audio").not(this).each(function (index, audio) {
    audio.pause();
  });
});
//Must be added at the bottom in HTML CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for: 
**[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/GgPmv/)**

**Html:**

```
<audio id="audio" controls>
</audio>
<audio id="audio1" controls>    
</audio>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("audio").each(function(){
  $(this).bind("play",stopAll);
});

function stopAll(e){
    var currentElementId=$(e.currentTarget).attr("id");
    $("audio").each(function(){
        var $this=$(this);
        var elementId=$this.attr("id");
        if(elementId!=currentElementId){
            $this[0].pause();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thats easy with jquery. below is an example of both audio and video

```
$("audio").on("play", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $("audio").not(this).each(function(index, audio) {
        audio.pause();
    });
});

$("video").on("play", function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');

    $("video").not(this).each(function(index, video) {
        video.pause();
    });
});
```