# onEnded event not working if I embed in tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have below html

```
 <audio controls onended="alert(1);this.currentTime = 0">
      <source src="{src}" type="audio/mpeg">
 </audio>
```

But onEnded event is not firing. How can I solve this issue, anything wrong with my code?. I do not want to add it using JavaScript addEventListener as I will embedding many elements dynamically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6312714/adding-event-listener-to-audio-html5-tag-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working fiddle with just html as you asked
http://jsfiddle.net/jVTbM/

```
 <audio id="audio" controls onended="alert(1);this.currentTime = 0">
    <source src="http://198.199.67.105:3412/downloadaudio/5379e4c988ff5235126d2ce9.3gpp" type='audio/ogg' />  
</audio>
```

Comment: I am embedding type="audio/mpeg", and source is of ".3gpp" type, is that causing the problem?

Comment: use type audio/3gpp with that extension

Comment: it is not playing at all in Chrome.

Comment: the problem is your file. It seems to be corrupted or with some error.

Comment: Hmmm, if I download it and play it is playing fine!

Comment: in my machine it display an error message (corrupted file)

Comment: thanks a lot! Android encoders behaving different in different devices