# Audio loaded event in Vue (Nuxt)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, html5-audio

I have a Nuxt-based gsap (greensock) animation, where I'm trying to start that animation only when an audio track that I'm loading is available.

The HTML for the audio:

```html
<audio id="explainer_nar" preload="auto">
  <source src="/audio/explainer-nar.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  <source src="/audio/explainer-nar.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

I have my gsap timeline stored in a method called `gsap_anim`. In that method I start the audio above using:

```js
const narration = document.getElementById('explainer_nar')
narration.currentTime = 0
narration.play()
```

Now, in my mounted, I want to wait for audio to be loaded BEFORE I start my animation, because when I just use the following:

```js
mounted() {
  this.gsap_anim()
}
```

The audio doesn't play (presumably because it hasn't loaded yet).

So, in Vue (and specifically Nuxt), how do I set a listener for the HTML5 audio element, so that I only play the `gsap_anim` method when it's loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<audio>` element emits a [`canplay` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplay_event) when the browser *has enough data to begin playing*, and the [`canplaythrough` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event) when the *full media clip is loaded can be played to its end*.

You can add an event listener for `canplay`/`canplaythrough` that performs the GSAP animation:

```js
const narration = document.getElementById('explainer_nar')

narration.addEventListener('canplay', () => {
  // GSAP animation code here...
})

narration.currentTime = 0
narration.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6313040/8816585

Also, if you want to be sure that this is an eventListener issue, you could load your page and then aim towards your browser devtools to send this into the console and see if `narration.play()` is playing or not.

That way you will be sure if it's because it has not loaded yet or if it's another issue.